# show input form control on initial page load for the default radio button selected in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a page where i am showing textbox control based on radio button selection. I am able to display the the textbox when i switch from one radio button to another. In my code I have radio button "Male" selected by default, how do i show first input control by default on initial load of the page.

**HTML Page**

```html
<div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['gender']" (click)="setradio('Male')" checked="checked">
                Male
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['gender']" (click)="setradio('Female')">
                Female
            </label>
        </div>

        <!--<div *ngIf="edited">-->


            <div *ngIf="isSelected('Male')" >
                <input type="text"/>test   
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="isSelected('Female')">
                <input type="text"/> test2
            </div>
```

**Component class:**

```ts
private selectedLink: string;
setradio(e: string): void {

    this.selectedLink = e;        
}

isSelected(name: string): boolean {

    if (!this.selectedLink) { 
        return false;
    }

    return (this.selectedLink === name); 
}
```

I have tried setting the default value as true for `*ngIf="isSelected('Male')=='true'` but it didn't work. Is there any other way which makes the input control to be displayed on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ts
private selectedLink: string = 'Male';
```

when you first loaded the template the first control is checked. The same thing if you set initially `selectedLink='Male'` the first input will be shown.

Comment: Thanks @Roman, It worked like charm. although text need to be edited from "Mail" to "Male" :) .